# How is that people are so closed minded?

Tags: discussion, scope

I thought this place was the correct for request for share great pieces of code that you have found in your programming life/experience... but I found no fruit on the request... yes, maybe it is not a question, but at the end is a programming request, I mean, I can't  go reading all the code on internet because there is no recommended authors like on a library, so help me learn where the great pieces/snippets of code are please if you have found any one in your programming life.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631987/learning-to-program-as-in-poetry

If I need to rephrase (because the down votes doesn't say a thing and the closes less).

Comment: You appear to be looking to looking to write a blog post. That is neither a question nor an answer.

Comment: so how I should write something that is a question for you to share great pieces of code???

Comment: You get a blog... or you use a site that is intended for polling an discussion rather than Q&A.

Comment: and lol... it appears that here in meta too... I would say LOOOL.

Comment: You misunderstand what votes mean in meta. Down-votes don't mean that people think that your meta question is bad, but rather just that folks disagree with your meta question's premise. So be happy that you get votes in meta since that means that your question is getting attention. It also means that your inappropriate blog post is *also* getting attention and will feel the so-called "meta" effect from this attention.

Comment: Leave or stay as you wish, but if you stay, your experience will be better if you go through the [help] section to see what questions should and shouldn't be posted on SO.

Comment: no I got that Stackoverflow is not a good site to ask those type of questions... I love it too... but I have found once or another time to much "it is not good"... still can have answers... but people will not do it because they will also get down votes... (yeah I have seen that too, even that they care a little more about the OP)

Comment: No, simply asking for good code samples is horrifically off-topic here. Note all the *other* list questions are deleted or historically locked as well. This site is set up for direct, answerable questions. More importantly, those questions solve a problem and are written in such a way that *future* users can find it via search engine and thus solve their problem as well. Your kind of question doesn't accomplish that mission **at all** and so it gets rightfully downvoted and closed.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I got it, but it all goes down to how people will write such answer to such question... guess nobody know how to write a good answer to that question for be "searchable". (I just found the source of all this :))

Comment: @tyoc213 I truly believe that it is impossible to write that question, or *any* answers to it, in a way that is compatible with this community's goals, rules, and standards. So no, it doesn't really boil down to that, as the entire *premise* is off-topic. Do consider chatting in the tavern if you want to discuss this at length: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/the-so-tavern-free-snacks

Comment: LOOOOOOOL I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT I'M DOING BUT IT'S YOU THAT IS CLOSED MINDED LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOL

Comment: hahahaha lol, yeah :) thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 15):

Your question seems to be a request for people to link you to "precious gems of code that have impacted you some way or other your programming skills".

That's [off-topic on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You shouldn't ask this question here because it's not a good fit for the site.

Comment: Where i could ask this type of questions... I mean, here is one of the most large place that I know of programming, so here should be a lot of experience that can share at less like I shared 2 examples.

Comment: any recommendation of a good site??? (not this stack overflow for sure)

Comment: @tyoc213 recommendations for off-site resources are off-topic. Note also that most of us on Meta are here because we *like* SO... If you just want to share your code, get a GitHub account.

Comment: so we enter on a infinite loop... this was so fun XD.

Comment: @tyoc213 You should try on a more discussion-oriented internet forum, maybe. I don't have any place in particular to recommend you, but the Internet is pretty big.

Comment: @tyoc213 Quora, perhaps? Even there, though, the question should at least be clear - are you trying to establish a sort of canon of great code?

Comment: I think of reddit at less... I guess it is a more enjoyable site with a large community too... IM to SAD that this request/quest was unfavorable to me... I wanted to send my students to learn something more extra... I thought for a moment that was a good place to have more sources that what I have as experience... :) but it is not.

Comment: thanks anyway (good that I have some points so that people can be happy doing down votes hahahahahhahahahaha)

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks :) Im trying to get more good to read code for teach to my folks/students :)... that was what I was trying to do.

Comment: @tyoc213 from Programmers.SE's meta: [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6742/40980) which includes some suggestions along with the background of the problem with discussions on Q&A sites.

Comment: @MichaelT "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat. Just questions... and answers." AFAIK I didn't want a discussion... I wanted answers about more code (not copy paste code, but share knowledge of experience)... what I wrote was an example of an answer I wanted to get (yes the 2 examples....) but anyway nobody here did get it like I wanted.

Comment: and the one that send me to get a "github account"... because "share code"... lol... just way off the line... you didn't get near to what I was asking :).

Comment: @tyoc213: Have you considered that possibly people *did* "get it like [you] wanted", but still think the question doesn't belong here? You still seem to be under the impression that everyone else is wrong on that front...

Comment: @tyoc213 You'd be allowed to ask that question on Yahoo! Answers.

Comment: lol not there...

Comment: @JonSkeet yep, still they could have answered (if they wanted, even that eventuall the question will be closed)... one answer was still good for me :). Questions should be asked and if possible answered, but anyway, thanks.

Comment: @tyoc213: No, they shouldn't. If a question doesn't belong here, it should be closed and deleted as quickly as possible, IMO... to keep the overall quality level as high as possible.

Comment: yeah, whatever :) I got it.

Comment: @tyoc213 while it is a very interesting question (no kidding), it's NOT suited for stack. and the idea of "they can still answer even if the question is bad" should not be an idea we promote. How do we improve on quality if all questions, even crappy ones, get answered? no one will care about being on topic, they'll just ask, get an answer, get their question closed, then move on. I understand it can be frustrating, but right now you're trying to use a hammer to hammer a screw.... find a screw driver :)

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: `"yeah, whatever"` -- good to know we have an enthusiastic supporter of maintaining the quality of this site.